# Regex to replace a string between special characters in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a situation where I have a string in which I have to replace a part that lies between special characters. 
I can do the same using substrings and length,but that is the dirty way. 
Is there any better way of doing this using regex?

e.g. of the string is

```
string str1 = "This is the <![CDATA[ SampleDataThatNeedsToBeReplaced ]]";
string repl = "Replacement Text";
```

I need a regex to get the output as

```
This is the Replacement Text
```

I did try a few regex like the following

```
 result = Regex.Replace(str1, @"(?<=CDATA\[)(\w+?)(?=\]\])", repl);
```

I also tried

```
Regex x = new Regex("(\\[CDATA\\])(.*?)(\\[\\]\\]\\])");
string Result = str1.Replace(text, "$1" + repl + "$3");
```

did not get any results.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use `string.Replace` method then seems like that would be easier vs you struggling with `Regex`

Comment: thats what I am doing right now, but it looks very dirty since I have to get the start index, end index, then substrings then concatenate. So if it can be done using regex.. the dirty part can be skipped

Comment: so where is `text` coming from.. when you show code please show all examples of your string and what your expected outcome is supposed to look like

Comment: Seems like that text comes from an xml. If so, you can use an xml parser... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace (
    "This is the <![CDATA[ SampleDataThatNeedsToBeReplaced ]]",
    @"<!\[CDATA\[(.+)]]",
    "Replacement Text");
```

Note that in case you need it ; the old text (between the inner brackets) is available as group1 (and so can be referenced via `$1`)